# What is this extra light on my headlights?

Tags: electrical, mazda, headlight, mazda-6

I own a [2006 Mazda 6 Luxury Sport](http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2006-mazda-6-luxury-sports-manual/SPOT-ITM-249820) in Australia, and the front headlights have 4 lights on them:

[image: Front headlight, all lights off]

It also has a fog light, which is not featured in this photo (but will be visible in later photos).

I cannot work out what one of the lights does (second from the left). The following 4 photos show the car with various lights on, explained below:

[image: Front headlights, lights on]

1. Parking lights on: you can kinda see the small light on the big globe on, as well as the fog light
2. Headlights on: you can see all of the above lights on, plus the full headlight on the right-hand side
3. High beams: you can see all of the above, plus the large globe on (well, admittedly you can't really see the small light on)
4. High beams + indicator: you can see all of the above, plus the indicator on

In none of the above can you see the second light from the left on. It is also possible to turn the fog light off (it's worth noting that in the picture shown, I have the fog light on, but that can be switched off which results in the light being off, as shown):

[image: Fog light]

Looking through the [Owners manual](https://www.mazda.ca/globalassets/en/pdf/manuals/mazda6/2006mazda6_ownersmanual_en.pdf) (pdf link) section 8-43, there is no light shed on the situation:

[image: Owners manual]

What is the light, second from the left, for? I have tried Googling results, but all I can find is about purchasing after-market headlights for the car.

I have tried to determine if there is even a light there, but I'm not that mechanically skilled. To the best of my knowledge, the luxury sport model is the top-model Mazda6 (although arguably the [MPS](http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2006-mazda-6-mps-manual-4wd/SPOT-ITM-249816) is) so should contain all the bells and whistles.

Comment: It may be a daytime running lamp.

Comment: Smart cruise control sensor?  Is there wiring running to the back of that area of the headlamp?

Comment: @Ben How would I know if it's a daytime running lamp? The car was running throughout the entire shoot (otherwise the high beams wouldn't work). The owners manual does mention "Daylight running lights (Canada)" in section 5-42, but it might just indicate the actual parking lights other lights shown above.

Comment: daytime running lamps should be on anytime the ambient light sensor is in sunlight. it may be on the dash near the bottom of the windshield. if you cover it and the lights go off and the headlights come on if you have autolamps then drls is correct. there may also be a fuse in the under hood fuse box you could pull to confirm. or its as @zaid said and the lights are ornamental. if it is a drl there should also be a small bulb in the housing.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but the MPS isn't a turbo diesel (L3T DISI petrol), and the MPS Luxury is actually the top-tier of the GG platform. If it's a late-05 or 06-onwards GG it's just a placeholder for where the foglight would be.... You need to retrofit from an earlier 02-04 model if you want them.

Comment: @AaronLavers Thanks for the info. The [MPS turbo](http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2006-mazda-6-mps-manual-4wd/SPOT-ITM-249816) I was speaking of isn't a diesel (not sure why I thought so, perhaps I was confusing it with the [newer diesels](http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/new/details/2016-mazda-6-atenza-auto/SPOT-ITM-435926)) but it is turbo intercooled. What MPS Luxury are you referring to? I did research before purchasing the car, and couldn't find anything better than the Luxury Sports. The earlier models mentioned also appear to have separate foglights

Comment: @Tas yeah, and even in the diesel it's a good car. The MPS6 sat above the 6 Luxury in the range, and then came in two trim levels. Sport (Which is what I have) has cloth seats and no sun roof, and then the Luxury which had leather seats, Bose sound, a sunroof and a few other little bits. Before I bought mine around 5 years ago I never knew how wide the range was

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.6crew.com/forum/showthread.php?22197-The-Official-6Crew-HID-Information-Thread-ALL-YOU-NEED-TO-KNOW) that extra space is for the integrated fog light, which is probably where the fog light would be if you didn't have the separate fog light.
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer for these cars (GG Platform). Late 05/06 onwards  didn't have the integrated fogs if they were delivered with separate fog-lights.

Comment: Strange, what's the purpose of having a designated place for both integrated headlight and bumper foglights?

Comment: Are you suggesting then that the [models _without_ the separate foglight](http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2006-mazda-6-classic-manual/SPOT-ITM-249812) contain the integrated foglight you mention, but not the top model ones? The owners manual appears to be for all models (a bit lazy, but understandable), but still doesn't appear to reference the integrated light; however, your reference holds and this does appear correct regardless

Comment: @Tas Fwiw some guy [here](http://forum.mazda6club.com/electrical/211817-2006-2007-s-hid-fog-lamp-questions.html) states that *all* 06-07 models have the fog lights on the lower bumper. Can only guess why; two data points are: fog lights at headlight level wouldn't make very good fog lights in the first place (possibly a design realization that happened too late to change the enclosure design), and apparently the 03 Mazda 6's had a recall from that same design where the integrated fog light sockets would warp from heat and fall out (recall fix was to install holding springs + clips).

Comment: Also I can't tell from the pic but if the integrated fog lights don't meet all the specs in http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinodisp/au/legis/nt/consol_reg/avsr324/s105.html and http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nt/consol_reg/avsr324/s176.html#front_fog_light then they wouldn't be suitable for Australian road use. If that's the case (or if there are enough countries where the integrated lights are not appropriate, even if it's OK in Australia) that could also perhaps explain why they aren't used.

Comment: I have 2004 Mazda 6 GG, with integrated fog lights. However, they do not work. I also do not have fog lights on the lower bumper. I have already checked the Fuse box, which seems pretty OK. Also, when I switch the fog lights ON, I do see the Reverse lights turning on, so the switch itself works. I also do not think that both of the fog lights bulbs need replacement. So, there is a great chance that either the fog lights are just as decor, or there is something wrong with the electronics. What do you think?